# How to convert Writer to String

Tags: java, android, string, io

```
 Writer writer = new Writer();
 String data = writer.toString();/* the value is not casting and displaying null...*/
```

Is there any other way to convert a writer to string?

Comment: You should perhaps read the documentation for how to use [Writer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Writer.html) because you can't even initialize it like that as it is abstract

Comment: Can you show how you are adding items to the writer?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I would use a specialized writer if I wanted to make a String out of it.

```
Writer writer = new StringWriter();
String data = writer.toString(); // now it works fine
```

Answer (score 12):

Several answers suggest using `StringWriter`.
It's important to realize that **`StringWriter` uses `StringBuffer`** internally, meaning that it's *thread-safe* and has a significant *synchronization overhead*.

- If you need thread-safety for the writer, then `StringWriter` is the way to go.
- If you don't need a thread safe `Writer` (i.e. the writer is only used as a local variable in a single method) and you care for performance — **consider using [`StringBuilderWriter`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/io/output/StringBuilderWriter.html)** from the [commons-io library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/).

`StringBuilderWriter` is almost the same as `StringWriter`, but uses `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`.

Sample usage:

```
Writer writer = new StringBuilderWriter();
String data = writer.toString();
```

Note — [Log4j has its own StringBuilderWriter implementation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/util/StringBuilderWriter.html) which is almost identical to the commons-io version.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a `Writer` implementation that results in a `String`, [use a `StringWriter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/StringWriter.html).